# Recursive Delete SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm searching a way to do a recursive delete on a table.
The situation is that table have 3 foreign key 1 on itself and 2 others, I want to delete depending on the date of the occurrence.

```
    Table1 --> Id1,    dateOCC,   ParentID
               1,  13-12-26,   null
               2,  13-07-18,   null
               3,  14-12-31,   1
               4,  13-06-26,   1
               5,  14-07-23,   null
               6,  13-07-22,   2 
   Table2--> ID, stuff

   Table3 --> ID, stuff
```

The ID of Table 2 and Table 3 are linked directly on ID of Table1.
The amount of data inside table 1 is approximately 20 000 000 row and the others table is approximately the same amount.

Here is on of the request I tried(its inside of a cursor who delete the data returned.

```
SELECT EO.ID,
     EO.DATEOCC,
     EO.PARENTID
    FROM TABLE1 EO
    WHERE EO.DATEOCC <= TO_DATE ('2013-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = EO.ID)
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 WHERE ID = EO.ID)
    START WITH EO.PARENTID IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR EO.ID = EO.PARENTID;
```

This request is really really slow to output the data that I want.
And it seems that is not return the data that I need to delete.

**Edit #1**
Ok so heres an example of what I need to do(In this example I suppose that the table 2 and table 3 have no matching ID on Table 1)

```
Table1 --> Id1,    dateOCC,   ParentID
                   1,  13-12-26,   null
                   2,  13-07-18,   null
                   3,  14-12-31,   1
                   4,  13-06-26,   1
                   5,  14-07-23,   null
                   6,  13-07-22,   2
```

After the delete sequence the table have to be like that if the >= date is 13-12-31

```
Table1 --> Id1,    dateOCC,   ParentID
                       1,  13-12-26,   null
                       3,  14-12-31,   1
                       5,  14-07-23,   null
```

So as you can see I delte the child that I can delete with his parent if possible. If I cant delete his parent because another child exist and I cant delete it I dont delete de parent(delete only the child that I can).

Answer (score 0):

In a hierarchical query, the `WHERE` clause is applied *after* the `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY` are used to build the hierarchy.  But syntactically it comes first, which makes it intuitively seem that it will be applied first.

If what you really want is to apply the `WHERE` clause first, then build the hierarchy, you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT EO.ID,
     EO.DATEOCC,
     EO.PARENTID
    FROM (
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1 EO
      WHERE EO.DATEOCC <= TO_DATE ('2013-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID = EO.ID)
      AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 WHERE ID = EO.ID)
    ) EO
    START WITH EO.PARENTID IS NULL
    CONNECT BY PRIOR EO.ID = EO.PARENTID;
```

But it is not clear whether that is what you want.  This would give you the top-level parents within the desired date range, and without children in the other tables, then build the entire hierarchy for those parents.  It's possible that lower nodes in the hierarchy would have children in the other tables, which would cause the delete to fail.

If that's not what you want, I think you need to describe your requirements more clearly.

Comment: Hi , what I want is to select all the occurence who have no parents or their parents are gonna get deleted too. I need to respect the foreign key constraints too.

After that I have a code to delete every row returned by the select.

Comment: But what does the date filter apply to?  For instance, in the sample data you gave in the question, record 1 matches the date filter, so I think you'd want to delete it; but there are two records that have record 1 as their parent, and one of them matches the date filter but the other doesn't.  Does this mean you want to delete all of them or none of them?  Or delete the ones that match the date filter and change the other one to point to a different parent?